# UDF: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, apache-spark

When I execute this code, I get the error `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`:

```
def calculate(num1, num2):
    if (num1/num2 > 1): 
        num1 = num2
    result = (num1 - num2) / math.sqrt(1-(num1/num2))
    return result   
df = udf(calculate, FloatType())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the error occurring? I just copied and pasted your function into an ipython session and it worked fine for me. The final line looks like it requires imports from other libraries so I didn't try to execute that.

Comment: There's no problem of indentation in this piece of code.

Comment: You might be mixing tabs and spaces. I have seen tabs converted into spaces when posting code here.

Comment: @AngusWilliams: I get this: `df = udf(calculate, FloatType()) ^`. The sign `^` is put below last `)`.

Comment: This is not reproducible with the code shown, even looking at the raw source for the post. The reference for these issues is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722 , but this attempt at a question does not actually exemplify the problem, or any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted does not have an indentation error. Look at the line number that is reported in the error message. You will see something like this:

```
xxxx
    xxxxx
    xxxxx
   xxxxx
   ^ this is the unindent that is causing the problem
```

Comment: I get this: `df = udf(calculate, FloatType()) ^`. The sign `^` is put below last `)`.